# output closes prematurely when a pexpect subprocess returns variable outputs

Tags: python, terminal, pexpect

## The Problem

---

I want to interact with interactive terminal programs from Python scripts, these programs might not always be written in Python. I already managed to do it with `pexpect` and the class in the code snippet below but I struggle to find a way to capture **the whole output after each instruction**.

## The Context

---

I cannot capture the whole output of the command (all the lines) **and** keep the program alive for future inputs.
Let's say I want to do this:

```py
terminal.start("/path/to/executable/repl/file") # on start returns 3 lines of output
terminal.run_command("let a = fn(a) { a + 1 }") # this command return 1 line of output
terminal.run_command("var") # this command will return 2 lines of output
terminal.run_command("invalid = invalid") # this command returns 1 line of output
```

note that the amount of lines on each output **might vary** because I want to be able to run multiple interactive terminal programs.

### What I have tried

##### Attempt 1

I tried using `readlines` but as the documentation states

> Remember, because this reads until EOF that means the child process should have closed its stdout.

It means that when once I run that it will close my process for future instructions, which is not my expected behaviour. Anyways when I try it I get the following.

```py
def read(self):    
    return list(self.process.readlines())
```

For a reason unknown to me the program just does nothing, prints nothing, raises no error, just stays paused with no output whatsoever.

##### Attempt 2

Read each line until finding an empty line like this

```py
def read(self):
    val = self.process.readline()
    result = ""
    while val != "":
        result += val        
        val = self.process.readline()
    return result
```

Once again the same problem, the program pauses, prints no input, does nothing for a few seconds then it prints the error `pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded.`

##### Attempt 3

using `read_nonblocking` method causes my program to read only a few characters, so I use the first parameter `size` as follows.

```py
def read(self):
    return self.process.read_nonblocking(999999999)
```

Only then I get the expected behavior but only for a few commands, then it reads nothing, besides, If I put an even bigger number, an error on memory overflow is raised.

## The Code

---

This is the implementation of the `Terminal` class.

```py
import pexpect

class Terminal:

    process: pexpect.spawn

    def __init__(self):
        self.process = None

    def start(self, executable_file: str):
        '''
        run a command that returns an executable TUI program, returns the output, 
        (if present) of the initialization of program
        '''

        self.process = pexpect.spawn(executable_file, encoding="utf-8", maxread=1)
        return self.read()

    def read(self):
        '''return entire output of last executed command'''
        return self.process.readline() # when executed more than amoutn of output program breaks

    def write(self, message):
        '''send value to program through keyboard input'''
        self.process.sendline(message)

    def terminate(self):
        '''kill process/program and restart property value to None'''
        self.process.kill()
        self.process.wait()
        self.process = None

    def run_command(self, command: str):
        '''
        run an instruction for the executed program 
        and get the returned result as string
        '''
        self.write(command)
        return self.read()
```

How I consume the class. This is what I run to test on each attempt mentioned above

```py
from terminal import Terminal

term = Terminal()

print(term.start("/path/to/executable/repl/file"), end="")
print(term.run_command("let a = fn(a) { a + 1 }"), end="")
print(term.run_command("a(1)"), end="")
print(term.run_command("let b = [1,2,4]"), end="")
print(term.run_command("b[0]"), end="")
print(term.run_command("b[1]"), end="")
print(term.run_command("a(2)"), end="")
```

If you want to know what kind of *specific* programs I want to run, its just these two [1](https://github.com/carepollo/hangman) and [2](https://github.com/carepollo/esolang) at the moment but I expect to add more in the future.

Comment: can you post the code where you call the functions `read`/`write`/etc please?

Comment: You're basically asking how to write a web shell in python, which is way too broad of a topic. Also, tools like that already exist in a multitude of languages, probably in python as well.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the problem comes from detecting when the command you sent to the console program has finished writing output.

I started by creating a very simple console program with input and output : `echo`. It just writes back what you wrote.

Here it is :

`echo.py`

```py
import sys

print("Welcome to PythonEcho Ultimate Edition 2023")

while True:
    new_line = sys.stdin.readline()
    print(new_line, file=sys.stdout, end="")  # because the line already has an \n at the end
    print("")  # an empty line, because that's how the webshell detects the output for this command has ended
```

It is a slightly modified version, that prints a line at the start (because that's what your `startProgram()` expects when doing `terminal.read()`) and an empty line after each echo (because that's how your `runCommand` detected that the output finished).

I did without Flask, because it is not needed for making the communication with the console program to work, and helps with debug (see [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). So here is the code I used :

`main.py`

```py
import subprocess


class Terminal:

    def __init__(self):
        self.process = None

    def start(self, executable_file):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(
            executable_file,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE
        )

    def read(self):
        return self.process.stdout.readline().decode("utf-8")
    #                                   no `.strip()` there  ^^^^^^^^

    def write(self, message):
        self.process.stdin.write(f"{message.strip()}\n".encode("utf-8"))
        self.process.stdin.flush()

    def terminate(self):
        self.process.stdin.close()
        self.process.terminate()
        self.process.wait(timeout=0.2)


terminal = Terminal()


def startProgram():
    terminal.start(["python3", "echo.py"])  # using my echo program
    return terminal.read()


def runCommand(command: str):
    terminal.write(command)
    result = ""
    line = "initialized to something else than \\n"
    while line != "\n":  # an empty line is considered a separator ?
        line = terminal.read()
        result += line
    return result


def stopProgram():
    terminal.terminate()
    return "connection terminated"


if __name__ == "__main__":  # for simple testing
    result = startProgram()
    print(result)
    result = runCommand("cmd1")
    print(result, end="")
    result = runCommand("cmd2")
    print(result, end="")
    result = stopProgram()
    print(result)
```

which gives me

```
Welcome to PythonEcho Ultimate Edition 2023

cmd1

cmd2

connection terminated
```

I removed the `split()` at the end of the `Terminal.read` otherwise the lines would not be correctly concatenated later in `runCommand` (or was it voluntary ?).
I changed the `runCommand` function to stop reading when it encounters an `\n` (which is an empty line, different from an empty string which would indicate the end of the stream). You did not explain how you detect that the output from your programs ended, you should take care to this.

Comment: no no, you are right about the split method, I was just trying different things, and about how should I detect the end of the output on each command I do not know, for each command may give different amount of lines of output. Apparently what I am trying to do is called **WebShell**, do you know any other documentation/tutorial/guide on how it is done? I am not really experienced myself on such topics myself.

Comment: You have the basis there, next you need to know better the console programs you want to interact with. Sorry, I don't know any specific resource for learning that.